# How to surround all selected SVG path elements with div in d3?

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

I have pre-created svg picture. My javascript selects elements with certain class and adds html tooltip if I  mouseover them. 
I have group of other elements linked to these hoverable elements by class name. 
I would like to surround these elements with border (not one by one, but all of them together) if I mouseover.

Do you have any idea how to do this in d3?

My javascript code looks like this (right now I was able to just change the stroke color on hover):

```
var HTMLmouseTip = d3.select("div.mouse.tooltip");
var tooltip = d3.selectAll(".tooltip:not(.css)"); 
var g = d3.select("svg").select("g"); 

var clusters = g.selectAll(".showTooltip")
            .on("mouseover", function(){
                tooltip.style("opacity", "1");
                heatmap.style("opacity", "1");
                tooltip.style("color", this.getAttribute("fill"));
                var id = this.getAttribute("id");
                HTMLmouseTip
                    .html(this.getAttribute("tooltip"))
                    .style("padding", 5 + "px");
                g.selectAll("."+id)
                    .style("stroke", "red");

            })
            .on("mousemove", function () {
                HTMLmouseTip
                    .style("left", Math.max(0, d3.event.pageX-120) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 20) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function () {
                return tooltip.style("opacity", "0");
            });
```

Thanks,

L.

Comment: just apply a border to the container div, i.e append all elements (the group) to the div and set the style on that div in css?

Comment: I thought the same way, but how do I 'move' the div over the selected elements? Or does append do that for me?
Like I have similar div like my HTMLtooltip and on hover I append all my elements to that div and change the border to solid?

Comment: sorry took a while, could you put together a fiddle so we can see what your problem is ?

Comment: Okei, I'm not sure how this fiddle works (I can't get this to work like it works in my own framework):
[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csLwqzrc/)

This is small and ugly part of my code (actually the result is one big dendrogram with heatmap). 

My svg is already created before js. What I want is that if I mouseover the red circle then the around the heatmap there comes rectangle or some border. Circle is connected to the right heatmap part with class name. My problem is that all the heatmap rectangles are separate elements and I want to show all them inside one big box.

Comment: which part is your heatmat ? D3 wasnt added in your code so i added it : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/csLwqzrc/1/, but you have variables that dont get initiated, for example:heatmap

Comment: Yes, this is the div I imagined I can use to cover the heatmap parts. 
This part doesn't work because I don't know how to move the div over the <g>s with class 'NODE_424'

Comment: Ahh i see, so all the heatmap elements have class of node_424 ?

Comment: Yes, and my real result has a lot of those circles and all the corresponding heatmap elements have class name from the circle. 
You can delete the heatmap part from d3, then tooltip works fine: [https://jsfiddle.net/csLwqzrc/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/csLwqzrc/4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you have a problem. This :

```
var tooltip = d3.selectAll(".tooltip:not(.css)");
```

Returns an array, so when you do :

```
 tooltip.style("opacity", "1");
```

Nothing happens as you have selected the array not the element in the array. So change to :

```
tooltip.each(function(d){
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", "1").style("color",'red')//
    })
```

The `.each(function(d){...` goes through the array and `d3.select(this)` selects the item in the array.

This now shows your tooltip on mouseover : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/csLwqzrc/3/

Now to get all your nodes in one `<g>` element.

Make a container :

```
var container = d3.select("svg").append("g").attr('id','nodeContainer')
```

Now select all nodes :

```
var heatmap = document.getElementsByClassName('NODE_424');
```

Select the container to append to :

```
var thisContainer = document.getElementById('nodeContainer');
```

Go through all nodes and add to container :

```
for(var i=0;i<heatmap.length;i++){
thisContainer.appendChild(heatmap[i])
}
```

Now you should be able to just add a border and youre done :)

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/csLwqzrc/5/

For the border, as you can't style `<g>` elements (they're used to group elements), you have to append a rect to the container and style that instead.

So you have to get the containers x and y to position the rect and width and height for rectangles size. `getBBox()` is the best way to do this.

```
var containerBBox =  document.getElementById('nodeContainer').getBBox();
```

This returns x,y,width,height.

Now append a rect with those attributes and your're done :

```
 container.append('rect')
  .attr('x', containerBBox.x)
  .attr('y', containerBBox.y)
  .attr('width', containerBBox.width)
  .attr('height', containerBBox.height)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'red')
  .style('stroke-width', 3)
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/csLwqzrc/6/

Now you only want to show the border on mouseover ? And remove on mouseout ?

On mouseover :

```
 container.style('stroke', 'red')
  .style('stroke-width', 3)
```

On mouseout :

```
container.style('stroke', 'none')
```

Final fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/csLwqzrc/11/

Comment: Thank You very much, you saved my day. 
This is exactly what I wanted: [https://jsfiddle.net/csLwqzrc/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/csLwqzrc/10/)

Comment: Regarding the for loop part, I notice that it appends over two nodes and thus some of the child <g> tags seem to be missing from the container. (I checked from web inspector)

In some cases this hides some parts of the container border. 

Any idea why this is so?

Comment: what do you mean by 'over two nodes' ?

Comment: If I open web inspector and look inside the 'nodeContainer', then there are groups with coordinates ( from transform=matrix(1,0,0,1,x,y)) 

For one column (x=176), there exist rows with y=87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99, 101, 103, 105, 107, 109, 111, 113, 115, 117. 

So there are some y coordinates missing and they are left to the initial part of svg. Why is that so?

Comment: If you check the length of 'heatmap', then it is 192. Printing out i in for loop also prints up to 192. 

But after appending, if you do:

    **var x = thisContainer.getElementsByClassName('NODE_424');**
      **console.log(x.length)**, then it prints 96.